# @Input Array if more than one is set on Angular component

Tags: angular

Suppose I have several @Inputs on my custom Angular component:

```
@Input()
public set inputOne(value: string) { ... }

@Input()
public set inputTwo(value: string) { ... }

@Input()
public set inputThree(value: string) { ... }
```

If I set more than one on my template:

`<my-component inputOne="Hello" inputTwo="World" inputThree="!"></my-component`

Would there be a way, possibly in the `constructor` or `ngOnInit` of my component, to access all of these through an array of some sort?

Does there exist an @Inputs array? Would I have to manually check for all inputs and if they're set, do something with them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just create one input var, which is an array:

```
@Input()
public set inputsArray(value: string[]) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Theres to ways

**Input array**

```
@Input() inputArray: string[];
```

Or Input Object with the string as properties it is to catch all inputs in the same object.

**Input Object**

```
export interface Inputs{
    inputOne: string;
    inputTwo: string;
    inputThree: string;
    ...
}

@Input() inputArray: Inputs;
```